# Is "there is free refill on that" idiomatic?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

I am not sure if this is idiomatic.

> The employee pumped petrol into the car and told the driver, who is a regular to the station, "there is
>   free refill on that".

Is it ok to say "on that"? The "on" doesn't sound very idiomatic.

Comment: What is the source of this quote please? Is it an expression you made up? If so what is the context for you to use it?

Comment: I've heard it a while ago while I was at a gas station.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of "on" seems perfectly natural. We can use "on" to mean "there is a special offer associated with that purchase".

> There's a 20% discount on men's clothing today!

The idea of an employee (I assume employed by the gas station) filling your car seems very odd to me (though I've seen it in old movies). And I've never heard of a gas station offering "free refills".

Comment: Some local jurisdictions still prohibit customers filling their own tank (no self-serve gas). Not sure where this took place, but free refills on gas sounds great to me. I guess the person was probably just joking though.

Comment: That'd be an interesting business model. I doubt they could sell enough snacks to make up for the cost of the gas, but maybe they could find a way.